# How to check if element exists in my for each loop

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to check if a element exists basically and if it does I want to open a url then back to the original page and then continue writing as it was. I tried a few approaches but they kept giving throwing exceptions. I added comments to the lines in question. I just cant figure out how to implement it.

```
                foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\\tumblrextract\\in7.txt"))
            {
                if (line.Contains("@"))
                {
                        searchEmail.SendKeys(line);
                        submitButton.Click();
                        var result = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("invite_someone_success")).Text;
                        if (driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("invite_someone_failure")).Count != 0)
                        // If invite_someone_failure exists open this url
                        driver.Url = "https://www.tumblr.com/lookup";
                        else
                        // Then back to following page and continue searchEmail.SendKeys(line); submitButton.Click(); write loop
                        driver.Url = "https://www.tumblr.com/following";
                        using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("C:\\tumblrextract\\out7.txt"))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(result + ":" + line);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the exception you are getting? probably it may be Null reference exception.  Please consider adding Null check in your code for the following

```
if(By.ClassName("invite_someone_success") != null){
var result = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("invite_someone_success")).Text;
}
```

Above is not verified/exact code, just a pseudo code

Comment: I have no exceptions I'm only trying to figure out how to implement                             the two commented lines in the code i posted. If invite_someone_failure exists load url https://www.tumblr.com/lookup then go back to the original url https://www.tumblr.com/following and continue read/write

Comment: Im getting the exception, I updated the code in the post. no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"invite_someone_success"}  My if/else statement doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Why don't you first save the element count /text in a variable and verify that they fetch the required values and then pass it to If Else?If Class name doesn't seem to work then why don't you try searching element with XPath? If you need help why don't you post the HTML source?

Answer (score 0):

you are using selenium and your might throw exceptions in some lines of code you have there - also take in consideration that i don't know tumblr website and it's html structure.

But first:

You're in a foreach loop and everytime you load at least once a page, all your elements will Stale, so this lines:

> var searchEmail = driver.FindElement(By.Name("follow_this"));
>
> var submitButton = driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit"));

will probably Stale in the next execution. (ElementStaleException).
Paste them too after:

> driver.Url = "https://www.tumblr.com/following";

Second:

when using FindElement method you have to make sure the element exists or an ElementNotFoundException will also be thrown.

> var result = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("invite_someone_success")).Text;
>
> var isThere = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("invite_someone_failure"));

the dotNet selenium client have a static (i believe) class to help with that it's the ExpectedCondition
that you can use to check if an element is present before trying to read it's text..

I Invite you to understand how selenium works, specially [StaleElementReferenceException](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp).

Have fun.